# How to calculate 'Duration' between two 'DateTimes'

Tags: scala, jodatime

I have two `DateTime` objects:

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, Hours}
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val t1: DateTime = DateTime.now
val t2: DateTime = /* Some other time in the future */
```

I want to calculate the duration between the two:

```
val d: Duration = Duration(t2 - t1)
```

Obviously the code above does not work. I tried `minus`, but that requires a `Duration`, not a `DateTime`.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Side note: joda-time has been discontinued since Java 8 came out. Of course I understand you may have to do with some old library, but I thought it was relevant to point it out.

Comment: @stefanobaghino No, the [Joda-Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is *not* discontinued. The project is in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode). The project recommends migrating to *java.time* if using Java 8 or later, but the library continues to be updated as needed.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I used the wrong word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val d = Duration(t2.getMillis - t1.getMillis, MILLISECONDS)
```

Answer (score 3):

## *Joda-Time*

Use [`org.joda.time.Duration`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html) constructor taking a pair of `DateTime` objects.

```
Duration d = new Duration( t1 , t2 ) ;
```

## *java.time*

Use the static factory method on the `java.time.Duration` class.

```
Duration d = Duration.between( t1 , t2 ) ;
```

Comment: @Basil Note that I'm using Scala and not Java. Also I can Have `Duration(3, Hours)` but `Duration(t1, t2) ` I'm getting "Cannot resolve overloaded method 'Duration'"

Comment: @A-Sharabiani Why are you trying to pass `3 , hours` when you want the duration between a pair of `DateTime` objects? Your Question is becoming quite confusing.

Comment: @BasilBourque I was trying to say I get compile error in your way. The way that it works in Scala and I don't get compile error is Duration(3, Hours), the other overload that you have in your answer does not exist. Please see the error message in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @stefanobaghino, try to use java.time which is available out of box since java 8. Regarding your case, check [this](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html#Duration(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant,%20org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)):

```
 Duration

public Duration(ReadableInstant start,
                ReadableInstant end)

    Creates a duration from the given interval endpoints.

    Parameters:
        start - interval start, null means now
        end - interval end, null means now 
    Throws:
        ArithmeticException - if the duration exceeds a 64 bit long
```

You was very close, hah